# Подключение библиотек CMake C++

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

Впервые начал использовать **CLion**. Хотел построить проект и потом просто открыть получившийся файл в папке дебага, но выдаёт ошибки об отсутствии библиотек.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перерыл полгугла, чтобы понять как настроить файл `CMakeLists.txt`, но так и не понял **как подключать библиотеки, которые нужны для работы...** (не вручную).

---

Текущее содержание файла:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(eolymp)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
add_executable(eolymp 909.cpp)
```

---

## UPD

Эту **проблему решил** добавлением этой строки `set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++")` в файл `CMakeLists.txt`.

Но! Теперь вылазит другая ошибка. Нужно подключать библиотеку `libwinpthread-1.dll`. Нашел подобный вопрос на *Англоязычном сайте*: [Вот он.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768515/how-to-do-static-linking-of-libwinpthread-1-dll-in-mingw) Но не полностью разобрался в нём.

---

## UPD 2

Проблему решил. Файл `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(eolymp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -static -lpthread")

add_executable(eolymp 909.cpp)
```

Один из ответов в другом вопросе:

> *These's no '-static-something' command, only standard libraries
>   (libgcc and libstdc++) can be set to static linking with one command.
>   For other libraries, you first switch to static linking with "-static"
>   and then list the libraries to include with separate commands, ie
>   "-lpthread"*

P.S. **Подождём на другие ответы :) Уже год ждём! :D**

Comment: Проблема не в CMake, а в том, что собранная программа зависит от mingw-шных рантайм библиотек - вместо того, чтобы линковать их статически, положите их в одну папку с приложением и все будет ок.

Comment: Не нужно запускать из папки Debug, запускайте из CLion. А если уж очень хочется из папки, то либо последуйте совету @VladimirGamalyan, либо добавьте путь к этим библиотекам в `$Path`. Добавлять флаги статической линковки в CMake это точно не выход.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan, но как мне знать какие библиотеки понадобятся? И потом ещё й вручную искать их и кидать в папку с проектом..? Не внушает доверия) Например вот после постройки проекта в **Code::Block** программа запускается без каких-либо ошибок и сам `.exe` файл весил меньше чем в **CLion**. Каким образом там происходит подключение этих библиотек?

Comment: @entithat Вы, как автор, должны знать, что используется в вашей программе, и предоставить все необходимые библиотеки конечному пользователю. От среды разработки это не зависит. В Code::Block, предполагаю, библиотеки уже находились в одной из директорий, где система может их найти, поэтому создавалось впечатление, что все работает само по себе (но на другом компьютере могло бы не запуститься).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас проблемы уже при запуске. CMake здесь не имеет силы.

Добавьте в переменную PATH директорию bin компилятора.
Для распространения программы (под Windows), поместите соответствующие библиотеки в директорию с программой, либо линкуйте статически необходимые библиотеки.